# Error with prewarming VersatileImageField

Tags: django, django-models

I've implemented [django-versatileimagefield](https://github.com/respondcreate/django-versatileimagefield) and have gotten it to a state where I can successfully resize images in templates with the use of the following tag, for example:

As a result, I'm confident that my form.py, view.py, and template works. I have, however, recently tried to 'prewarm' the images so that when a user saves an image, a set of resized images are saved to my 'media' folder. This prevents the server from having to resize dynamically on every page load and can just grab the correctly sized image.

My problem is that when the user goes to save an image within the image upload form, they get an error.

Settings.py

```
VERSATILEIMAGEFIELD_SETTINGS = {
    'cache_length': 2592000,
    'cache_name': 'versatileimagefield_cache',
    'jpeg_resize_quality': 70,
    'sized_directory_name': '__sized__',
    'filtered_directory_name': '__filtered__',
    'placeholder_directory_name': '__placeholder__',
    'create_images_on_demand': False,
    'image_key_post_processor': None,
    'progressive_jpeg': False
}

VERSATILEIMAGEFIELD_RENDITION_KEY_SETS = {
    'image_gallery': [
        ('image_large', 'thumbnail__400x400'),
        ('image_small', 'thumbnail__900x900')
    ]
}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from versatileimagefield.fields import VersatileImageField
from django.dispatch import receiver
from versatileimagefield.image_warmer import VersatileImageFieldWarmer

class ImageGallery(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    image = VersatileImageField('image_gallery', upload_to=upload_location)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author.username                                          

@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=ImageGallery)
def warm_gallery_images(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    gallery_img_warmer = VersatileImageFieldWarmer(
        instance_or_queryset=instance,
        rendition_key_set='image_gallery',
        image_attr='image_small'
    )
    num_created, failed_to_create = gallery_img_warmer.warm()
```

Traceback

```
Environment:



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\jason\Desktop\jason\accounts\views.py" in imagegallery
  513.                 instance.save()

File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  729.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  769.                 update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,

File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in send
  178.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in <listcomp>
  178.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "C:\Users\jason\Desktop\jason\accounts\models.py" in warm_gallery_images
  177.     num_created, failed_to_create = gallery_img_warmer.warm()

File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\versatileimagefield\image_warmer.py" in warm
  143.                     reduce(getattr, self.image_attr.split("."), instance)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /accounts/profile/websitesetup5/upload/
Exception Value: 'ImageGallery' object has no attribute 'image_small'
```

I feel like I've followed the instructions on this page, but I'm still getting this error.

http://django-versatileimagefield.readthedocs.io/en/latest/improving_performance.html#turning-off-on-demand-image-creation

I should note that I do NOT have django REST framework installed. My understanding is that it's not required for this post-save method of prewarming images.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I haven't used versatileimagefield, but perhaps you should have `image_attr='image'` instead of `image_attr='image_small'`.

Comment: Wow, I think that that may have worked!!!!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `image_attr` field should point to the model field `image`:

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=ImageGallery)
def warm_gallery_images(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    gallery_img_warmer = VersatileImageFieldWarmer(
        instance_or_queryset=instance,
        rendition_key_set='image_gallery',
        image_attr='image'
    )
    num_created, failed_to_create = gallery_img_warmer.warm()
```